# How to set up Travis CI and postgresql using custom db credentials?

Tags: travis-ci

I'm trying to set up custom Postgres credentials with Travis CI as I'd like to avoid the existing credentials definition in the code to be tested.

The testing code defines that the database should be accessed on:

```
'sqlalchemy.url': 'postgresql://foo:bar@localhost/testing_db'
```

I've therefore created a `database.travis.yml` file:

```
postgresql: &postgresql
adapter: postgresql
username: foo
password: bar
database: testing_db
```

...and added the following to my `.travis.yml`:

```
services:
  - postgresql

before_script:
  - psql -c 'create database stalker_test;' -U postgres
  - mkdir config && cp database.travis.yml config/database.yml
```

However, I am still getting this during testing:

```
OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) FATAL:  role "foo" does not exist
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using Rails?

Comment: @HoriaComan No, I'm using Python.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Adding the following to `.travis.yml` solved my issue. No need for a `database.travis.yml` file.

```
before_script:
  - psql -c "CREATE DATABASE testing_db;" -U postgres
  - psql -c "CREATE USER foo WITH PASSWORD 'bar';" -U postgres
```

Comment: ...please how can I get access to the database url created...

Answer (score 0):

Database.yml seems to be a Ruby On Rails thing. Travis CI started with rails / ruby testing, so the [docs](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/database-setup/#PostgreSQL) might be reflecting that.

You most probably need to do your setup in a separate script or migration setup, and not rely on travis, except for running the service.